# Ignore 1 is to 1 of 2 values, but show other values

Tags: sql

In below table if for an item , there is 101 showing up, then equivalent amount of 111 for the same item should be ignore and only show the remaining 111 values.

( 1:1 of 101:111 should be ignored in output )

```
item|qty|batch|type

item1|2|ten|111

item1|2|ten|111

item1|2|ten|111

item1|2|ten|101

item1|4|ten|111

item2|2|five|111

item2|2|five|101

item2|2|five|111
```

so desired output will be as per below, how to obtain this..

```
item|qty|batch|type

item1|2|ten|111

item1|2|ten|111

item1|4|ten|111

item2|2|five|111
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `row_number` and `count` to check the difference between `type`.

```
select  item    
       ,qty 
       ,batch   
       ,type
from   (
        select item 
              ,qty  
              ,batch    
              ,type
              ,row_number() over(partition by item,qty,batch order by item)                             as rn
              ,count(case type when 111 then 1 end) over (partition by item,qty, batch order by item) - 
               count(case type when 101 then 1 end) over (partition by item,qty, batch order by item)   as dif
        from t
        ) t2
where rn <= dif and type = 111
```

| item | qty | batch | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 2 | ten | 111 |
| item1 | 2 | ten | 111 |
| item1 | 4 | ten | 111 |
| item2 | 2 | five | 111 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6ace642516b17f78ef86161dce7550e4&hide=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
    select distinct(item),qty, batch, type
from(
SELECT item, qty, batch, type
FROM test
where type = 111)x
;
```

[DBFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de9c5cb/2) can check

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response, but i still have an issue with the output.  There are cases where the same values will be there for multiple rows, but they dont have a 101, but 111 only. have updated the question with additional row for data and required output. Can you help check so i get all the rows ,  and ignore only the 1:1 of 101:111, ie if there are 2X101 rows, then ignore 2X101  and 2X111 rows and dispaly all other 111 rows

Comment: @NewLearner `item1|2|ten|111` i dont understand why two times this in your output